# How can I display the results of a post request on the same html page? Flask app

Tags: python, flask, post, get

I have built a flask app that takes user input and displays info from wikipedia based on the word or phrase inputted. For some reason, I can't get the results to post on the same HTML page.

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyKtY.png)

[Flask, App.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99eZb.png)

I'd like to display the result in the last div.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please put your code samples in the actual body of your question instead of as links to images of code.  This will make the question more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a post request then some variable = true!
Then you pass this variable to the HTML page.
Then in the HTML page you check if the variable = true
and if it's true, then you show the result of the Wikipedia!

```
app.route(methods=["POST", "GET"])

check = False

text = "  "
```

if you get a post request:

```
    bla
    bla
    bla
    text = text you want to show
    check = True
    return render_template("result.html", check=check, text=text)
```

and then on the HTML page you check the variable with jinja:
HTML:

```
{% if check %} #if check = True

   {{ text }}  #show the text
```